# Checking if remote directory exists returns exit code 1, but the opposite option gets executed

Tags: bash, gitlab-ci

This check gets invoked:

```yaml
  - echo "Everything works fine until now."
  - >
     if ssh user@$TEST_SERVER '[ -d $BUILD_DIR ]'; then
       echo "Directory exists, continuing."
     else
       ssh user@$TEST_SERVER 'mkdir -p $BUILD_DIR'
     fi
  - scp some_script.sh user@$TEST_SERVER:$BUILD_DIR/
  - echo "I do not even get executed; previous line fails..."
```

In the output I can see the "Directory exists, continuing." sentence: the job continues as if the directory existed in the remote server, and then the line with `scp` command gets launched, failing to copy the script file to a non-existing directory.

When I make a check from my machine, launching the same command, I get an exit code 1:

```sh
$ ssh user@10.11.12.13 '[ -d /var/www/build_1 ]'
$ echo $?
1
```

What is wrong in there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> '[ -d $BUILD_DIR ]'
> ```

is inside single quotes, `BUILD_DIR` is not set **on the remote** so it expands to nothing, which expands to `[ -d ]`  - `-d` is not an empty string, so `[` exits with success.

You want:

> ```
> "[ -d $BUILD_DIR ]"
> ```

or yet better:

> ```
> "[ -d $(printf "%q" "$BUILD_DIR") ]"
> ```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks! For the record, what does exactly the `yet better` option does, and why is it better than the first one?

Comment: Try a directory with spaces. Like a dir named `'" a` like `BUILD_DIR="'\" a"`